# Children's Italian steampunk comic from 1970 with a trip to Mars HG Wells style. Earthlings taught the Martians to play football

Tags: story-identification, comics, mars, steampunk

This comic was almost certainly Italian and its author had a very Italian name, similar to "Ivo Milazzo", an excellent author of a western comic called Ken Parker. But I'm sure it's not Ivo Milazzo. The drawing style was elegant but quite childish and whimsy.

It might be too early to fit this comic into the steampunk genre, but it was set in the 19th century and the protagonists travelled in a sphere similar to the one propelled by HG Wells' "cavorite", but in this case the spaceship was propelled by steam and the travellers had to throw coal into the boilers using shovels. It's impossible to be more steampunk than that.

When they arrived on Mars they were involved in a war between two Martian kingdoms and achieved peace by teaching the Martians to play football (soccer) to settle their differences.

Comment: _"might be too early to fit this comic into the steampunk genre"_ If it's 1970 it definitely wasn't called Steampunk at the time, doesn't mean it might not fit the genre or be considered a precursor though.

Comment: @Pelinore English is not my native language and I gladly accept sugerences. Do you suggest "might be to early to be called steampunk at the time"?

Comment: Color or black and white?